# Firebase/Firestore How can I give a permission specific collections in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am developing a web service.

I was using below rule in my firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth!=null;
    }
  }
}
```

But I need to give 'write' permission specific collections.

For example, I have some collections like:

- /news
- /teams
- /matches

I want to add "comment" to them like:

- /news/{newsId}/comments
- /teams/{teamId}/comments
- /matches/{matchId}/comments

So I want to change the permission like:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth!=null;
    }

    match /news/{document=**}/comments/{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }

    match /teams/{document=**}/comments/{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }

    match /matches/{document=**}/comments/{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }

  }
}
```

But it doesn't work...

How can I solve this problem??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an illegal declaration:

```
match /news/{document=**}/comments/{document=**} {
```

you're using `document` as a path segment identifier twice in the same context, which isn't allowed. To make the rule valid, makes sure each path segment identifies has a unique name. For example:

```
match /news/{newsDocument}/comments/{commentsDocument=**} {
```

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining that you're using two glob wildcards in the same match, which is illegal (and doesn't really make sense).  Here's one of your matches:

```
match /news/{document=**}/comments/{document=**}
```

`{document=**}` is a **glob wildcard**.  That's what the ** is saying.  It is going to try to match multiple path segments.  But that's not what you want here.  What you want to match for the first wildcard is just any given document ID, like this:

```
match /news/{newsId}/comments/{document=**}
```

Now, you have `{newsId}` matching a document id under the news collection.  The glob wildcard is now matching any document or subcollection's document nested under `/news/{newsId}/comments`.